# Consulta sumatoria datos en una tabla con MySql o PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buen dia, quisiera me ayudaran con algo

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde se guardan las ventas o facturas, en ella esta el id del cliente (que para lo que preguntaré no es necesario) y la fecha de la venta

[image: TABLA VENTAS]

Aqui tengo la tabla del detalle de ventas donde se coloca el id del producto, el valor al cual se vendio, la cantidad y por supuesto en que venta fue facturado

[image: TABLA DETALLE DE VENTAS]

Quisiera saber si es posible con una consulta MySql, consultar por ejemplo:

Cuantos productos se vendieron de id=2 desde el 2020-01-14 hasta el 2020-01-15

O al menos con PHP, he intentado de la siguiente manera pero no he conseguido exito

```
<?php
//la consulta esta bien pues ya lo probé
$consulta_ventas=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2020-01-14' AND '2020-01-15'");

      $conteo = mysqli_num_rows($consulta_ventas);
//verifico que si existan ventas en ese rango de fechas
      if($conteo==0){echo json_encode("no hay ventas en ese rango de fecha");}
      else
      {
//como son 9 productos, empezando id=1, id=2, etc recorro los 9 id
        for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)
        {
          $total_cantidad_vendida_este_producto=0;
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_ventas))
          {
            $numero_venta = $row['numero_venta'];
              $detalle_venta=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM `detalle_venta` WHERE numero_venta = $numero_venta and id_producto=$i");
              $fila_detalle_venta=mysqli_fetch_array($detalle_venta);
              $cantidad=$fila_detalle_venta['cantidad'];
            $total_cantidad_vendida_este_producto=$total_cantidad_vendida_este_producto+$cantidad;
          }
          $cantidades_vendidas[] = array("id_producto"=>$i,"total_este_producto"=>$total_cantidad_vendida_este_producto);
        }
        echo json_encode($cantidades_vendidas);
      }
?>
```

Obtengo lo siguiente en el echo

[{"id_producto":1,"total_este_producto":16},{"id_producto":2,"total_este_producto":0},{"id_producto":3,"total_este_producto":0},{"id_producto":4,"total_este_producto":0},{"id_producto":5,"total_este_producto":0},{"id_producto":6,"total_este_producto":0},{"id_producto":7,"total_este_producto":0},{"id_producto":8,"total_este_producto":0},{"id_producto":9,"total_este_producto":0}]

Por lo cual en el id=1 si esta bien pues si son 16 unidades vendidas pero en la demas no funciona

Gracias!

Comment: por favor agrega lo que hayas  intentado al momento

Comment: @Aprendiz He modificado la pregunta, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Según veo hace falta entender un poquito más lógica relacional.
Posiblemente en tu código resulte mejor una consulta como la siguiente.

```
SELECT detalle_venta.id_producto, SUM(detalle_venta.cantidad) AS cant_total 
FROM detalle_venta
INNER JOIN ventas ON ventas.numero_venta = detalle_venta.numero_venta
WHERE ventas.fecha BETWEEN '2020-01-14' AND '2020-01-15'
GROUP BY detalle_venta.id_producto;
```

Resultado:

```
+------------+-----------+
|id_producto | cant_total|
+------------|-----------+
| 1          | 16        |
| 2          | 93        |
| 4          | 227       |
| 5          | 6         |
| 6          | 33        |
| 7          | 96        |
| 9          | 6         |
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz `INNER JOIN` con la tabla detalle y usa la *funcion de agregación* `sum()`:

```
SELECT sum(cantidad)
  FROM ventas
    INNER JOIN detalle_venta
      USING (numero_venta)
  WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2020-01-14' AND '2020-01-15'
    AND id_producto = 2
```